# phpStorm в typeScript не понимает конструкцию ?? и ожидает ?:

Tags: typescript, phpstorm

В коде вида

```
 {
    a: x ?? y
 }
```

PhpStorm показывает ошибку на второй вопросик и на конец строки, говоря ": expected"
Настроен на typescript 3.8.3 и в целом всё остальное работает.
Возможно это как-нибудь поправить?

Comment: ` *.ts ` - ok ? точно ли "Настроен на typescript 3.8.3"

Comment: проверил, в *.ts тоже так, убрал в вопросе эту информацию чтобы не путать. Да, точно на typescript 3.8.3 - в настройках проекта прописалась эта версия и вкладка внизу создалась с названием "TypeScript 3.8.3". Версия phpStorm 2018.3.6

Answer (score 0):

Поддержка оператора ?? началась с версии phpStorm 2019.3, так что нужно было просто скачать новую версию IDE.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006014139-Nullish-Coalescing-operator-support-for-upcoming-TypeScript-release

Comment: какая странная ситуация